# How can I set the charset=UTF-8 in Spring for Android?

Tags: android, spring

I have the following code:

```
  HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("text","plain;charset=UTF-8")));
```

However this throw me an IllegalArgumentException. The problem is that I want to set the charset as UTF-8 without change it from the config file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API doc `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if `MediaType` [fails](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.0.0/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java#MediaType.toString%28java.util.Collection%29) to convert itself to `String`.

Try the following:

```
requestHeaders.setAccept(
    Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
);
```